# Dockerfile COPY command puts an empty file in its container when overwriting another file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When copying files from host machine to container where a file already exists at the destination path, the copied file is empty.

I've attempted to copy the same files to a path with a different name and this works fine.

The two lines from my dockerfile that this issue happens on are:

```
COPY conf/policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6/

COPY conf/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

Full dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  git libmagick++-dev \
  --no-install-recommends && \
  git clone https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick.git && \
  cd imagick && git checkout master && phpize && ./configure && \
  make && make install && \
  docker-php-ext-enable imagick && \
  cd ../ && rm -rf imagick && \
  apt-get install -y ghostscript && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pecl install xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

COPY conf/php.ini /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/40-custom.ini
COPY conf/policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6/
COPY www/ /var/www/html/

COPY conf/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
COPY scripts/generate-ssl.sh /generate-ssl.sh

RUN chmod +x /generate-ssl.sh
RUN /bin/bash /generate-ssl.sh

EXPOSE 80 443
```

Is this intended behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Docker Documentation - Docerfile Copy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy):

> `COPY src dest`: If src is any kind of file, it is copied individually along with its metadata. In this case, if  ends with a trailing slash /, it will be considered a directory and the contents of  will be written at /base().

For your case try and specifiy the dest file:

```
COPY conf/policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml

COPY conf/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Otherwise i dont see anything wrong with your dockerfile